# Python 3 Gzip json for post on an API

Tags: json, python-3.x, gzip

Having a bit of trouble getting a gzipped JSON payload with python 3

```
def post_data ( data ) :
    method_name = json.loads(data)['subject'][4][0][1]
    instance = json.loads(data)['serialNumber']
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    utc_now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    not_after = datetime.datetime.strptime(json.loads(data)['notAfter'], "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y GMT" ).strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    days =  datetime.datetime.strptime(not_after, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")-\
            datetime.datetime.strptime(utc_now, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    values = days.days

raw_json = '''{"MetricReports":[{
                   "Metadata":{
                     "MinPeriod":"FiveMinute",
                     "MaxPeriod":"FiveMinute"
                   },
                   "Namespace":"Schema/Service",
                   "Metrics":[{
                       "Dimensions":{
                         "DataSet":"NONE",
                         "Marketplace":"PDX",
                         "HostGroup":"ALL",
                         "Host":"host.com",
                         "ServiceName":"Server",
                         "MethodName":"%s",
                         "Client":"ALL",
                         "MetricClass":"instance",
                         "Instance":"%s"
                       },
                       "MetricName":"daysToExpiry",
                       "Timestamp":"%s",
                       "Type":"MetricsLine",
                       "Unit":"None",
                       "Values":%s
                     }
                   ]}
                 ]}''' %(method_name, instance, timestamp, values)


headers = {'content-type' : 'application/x-gzip'}
putUrl = 'http://api-pdx.com/'
session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
region = 'us-west-2'
service = 'monitor-api'
auth = AWS4Auth(
            credentials.access_key,
            credentials.secret_key,
            region,
            service,
            session_token = credentials.token)

r = requests.post(url = putUrl, json = gzip.compress(raw_json) , auth = auth, headers = headers, verify=False)
print(r.content)

get_data()
post_data(data)
```

I need to compress the raw_json because the API is expecting a gzipped attachment.  The API is spitting back "The HTTP request is invalid. Reason: Invalid JSON attachment:Not in GZIP format" if I attempt to send the JSON as is.

I tried the gzip.compress, but it says : memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

so I tried gzip.compress(json.dumps(raw_json).encode('utf-8')) and that says Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Comment: Try to use `data` argument instead of `json`: `requests.post(url = putUrl, data= gzip.compress(json.dumps(raw_json).encode('utf-8')) , auth = auth, headers = headers, verify=False)`

Comment: Stanislav, please post that as the answer.  I want to give credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a binary data with `requests.post` method they should be passed as `data` argument, not as `json`:

```
requests.post(url = putUrl,
              data = gzip.compress(json.dumps(raw_json).encode('utf-8')),
              auth = auth,
              headers = headers,
              verify=False)
```